# With react-router is ite possible to access context from a Route's onEnter prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm looking how to control which routes are available, based on a users privilege level which is in the context.

I found [a nice example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow), but it relies on localStorage for storing user auth state. I would prefer to keep everything "in state".
I've been playing around for a while, but I can't seem to pass context into the `onEnter()` prop of a `<Route ... />`. My closest solutions are looking terribly hacky and I'm starting to think making react-router aware of context is a bad strategy.

Has anyone got an example? or can confirm the router is should not be making decisions based on context?

Thanks

Edit: I have been pointed to the react-router examples, it looks promising: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples

Comment: I am using react router and make use of onEnter to allow users access to different routes based on their authentication and access level. This works great.

I usually do this `onEnter={ RouterMiddleware.authenticatedUsersOnly }` and if i need to pass a store, I use this `onEnter={ (nextState, replace) => { RouterMiddleware.loginLevel(nextState, replace, store) } }`

You can look at react router documentation to check if and how you can access the context in its middlewares.

* Don't forget to handle the authentication + privilege level server side while processing user request.

Answer (score 1):

Although `localStorage` is pretty reliable, it might not be supported or user could delete it.

I would suggest you to use [redux](http://redux.js.org/) & [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) instead, then you can easily access the `state` of your application, code would look something like this:

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (

  function authenticateUser(nextState, replaceState, callback) {
     const state = store.getState()
     // do your thing - forbid, grant access etc...
  }

  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={authenticateUser} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Moreover `redux` helps you scale `react` applications. It might be a little difficult and overwhelming to understand `redux` at first, but it's ok - because the effort is well worth it and will pay off.
[Usage of redux with react-router.](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html)